# How I remove exception of Thread Abortion Error in C# desktop application

Tags: c#, multithreading, desktop

I want to remove or block exception in my C# desktop application. This problem is occurred when my project load its splash screen..

The code for splash screen calling is

```
private void SplashForm()
        {
            Splash newSplashForm = new Splash();
            newSplashForm.ShowDialog();
            newSplashForm.Dispose();
        }
```

and

```
 public MainForm(string filearg) {
             Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashForm));
             t1.Start();
             Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); // The amount of time we want our splash form visible
             t1.Abort();
             Thread.Sleep(7000);
}
```

how i can remove this exception

Comment: That is just wrong. Put a timer in splashform to call close. Write a static method, to create the form kick the timer off, Show it.

Comment: you can remove the exception removing t1.Abort();

Answer (score 2):

> how i can remove this exception
>
> ```
>    t1.Abort();
> ```

Don't call something that create that exception. Use a better inter-thread communication event to close down the worker thread cooperatively.

In this case call `Control.BeginInvoke` on the `Splash` instance to call its `Close` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void SplashForm()
    {
        try
        {
            Splash newSplashForm = new Splash();
            newSplashForm.ShowDialog();
            newSplashForm.Dispose();
        }
        catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
       {
            System.Threading.Thread.ResetAbort();
       }
    }
```

Of if you want to just ignore exception in you thread then just use empty catch block

```
    private void SplashForm()
    {
        try
        {
            Splash newSplashForm = new Splash();
            newSplashForm.ShowDialog();
            newSplashForm.Dispose();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```